# Mandar email dentro de um servidor local?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Eu tenho um site no meu `localhost` e gostaria de haver possibilidade de mandar emails. Tentei com a função `mail()` mas não consegui. Então encontrei uma forma usando `PHPMailer`.

Tenho o seguinte código

```
<?php

$oc=$_POST['razao'];
$rua=$_POST['rua'];
$freg=$_POST['freg'];
$texto = "
<h4>Declaração de uma Ocorrência</h4>
<br/>
<br/>
Ocorrência: ".$oc."<br/></br/>
Rua: ".$rua." da freguesia de ".$freg.";
";
require '../mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
echo "<script>console.log('".$texto."')</script>";
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->CharSet="utf-8";
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  // specify main and backup server
    $mail->Username = 'EMAIL';          // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'PASS'; // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                          // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->From = "b_sem_l@hotmail.com";
    $mail->FromName = "União de Freguesias de Antas e Abade de Vermoim";
    $mail->AddAddress("b_sem_l@hotmail.com", "Bruno Moutinho");
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = "Declaração de uma Ocorrência";
    $mail->Body    = $texto;

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
       echo "<script>console.log('".$mail->ErrorInfo."')</script>";
       exit;
    }else{
        echo "<script>console.log('Sucesso')</script>";
    }
?>
```

Todas as variáveis chegam lá direito. O envio é feito por `ajax` mas não tenho conseguido pois dá-me um erro na consola: `SMTP connect() failed.`.

Comment: @LINQ Mudei, continua a não dar

Comment: Você já liberou acesso aos apps menos seguros no Gmail? — https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: @LINQ Fiz isso agora, continua a não funcionar, mesmo erro

Comment: Já tentou usar seu email do gmail como remetente?

Comment: Deve ser problema com o certificado ssl (já que você ativou o less secure apps do gmail). Para confirmar tente alterar o modo de debug para `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2`. Coloque isso logo após instanciar o PHPMailer. Você deverá ver um erro relacionado a [falha no certificado ssl](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#php-56-certificate-verification-failure)

Comment: @Juven_v Fiz o que referiu, não deu esse erro, deu o mesmo erro.

Comment: @DvD Fiz o que disse, dá o mesmo erro.